# css border radius mouse hover fog?

Tags: html, css

I want a css button with border-radius, but I want this border to be well contoured.

when I put mouse hover this button there is a kind of fog in borders:

```
.b_b{
 cursor : pointer;
 padding:6px;
 font-size : 10pt;
 font-weight : bold;
 color : #2e9fff;
 text-decoration : none;
 border:1px solid #cce9ff;
 background:#fff;
 border-radius:9px;
 z-index:999px;
}
.b_b:hover{
 background-color:#2e9fff;
 color:#fff;
}

<span class=b_b>button</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/42fmsj20/

what is wrong?

Comment: Looks like plain old anti-aliasing...what I actually **can** see...it's pretty minor.

Comment: While dmitriy's answer does look nicer. At this point, if you're that worried about small details like that it's best to use sprites from photoshop as dynamic buttons. Not saying you have to, but if you want better detail, that's the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2zbu8btx/

```
`<span>` tag is used to determine the line elements of the document
```

add `display: inline-block;` for span

In fact, an element in its effect similar to recessed elements (such as tag `<img>`). At the same time its interior is formatted as a block element, and the element itself - as built.

https://jsfiddle.net/mgcLbo92/

```css
.b_b{
 cursor : pointer;
 display: inline-block;   
 padding:16px 50px;
 font-size : 10pt;
 font-weight : bold;
 color : #2e9fff;
 text-decoration : none;
 border:1px solid #cce9ff;
 background:#fff;
 border-radius:9px;
 z-index:999px;
}
.b_b:hover{
 background:#2e9fff;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<span class=b_b>button</span>
```

Comment: Can you explain **why** this solves the problem the OP is experiencing? I think it would be useful.

Comment: thank you! the button really looks nice but adding display inline block my button size getting bigger. can I add width and height?

Comment: @Dmitriy oh, thank you! I found the problem! in the button div I put line-height:60px; I think thats why my button was so big.. now its ok!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `background-clip` property to achieve this. For an in-depth description on how that property works you can check out the W3Schools example and explanation [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-clip.asp).

CSS:

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding;  /* Safari 4+, Chrome 6+ */
-moz-background-clip: padding;     /* Firefox 3.6+ */
background-clip: padding-box;      /* Firefox 4+, Safari 3+, Opera 10.5+, IE9+ */
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvw361ve/)

I also noticed the you had forgot to put **double quotes** `""` around your class value, make sure you always include those as they are required for valid syntax.

```
<span class="b_b">button</span>
```

Comment: Actually, quotes around attribute values are not mandatory in HTML5 (as opposed to XML and XHTML), as long as attribute value doesn't contain any whitespace or other dangerous character: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-unquoted

Comment: Wouldn't recommend at all, it's bad practice.

Comment: I agree, especially on class attribute. However, the quotes aren't required for valid syntax, so I just wanted to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is half aesthetical and half a matter of antialiasing.

When you put darker border around lighter element and then, on hover state, invert it to lighter border around darker element, you'll end in unpleasant effect like this, it will just look like the border is some kind of gradient on edges of the element. Your eye will not consider it as a border anymore since it does not delimit the area of element from the outer space.
Try adding darker border to hover state, you'll get rid of foggy effect and it will look nicer.

See updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/bd2h2h8b/

```
.b_b:hover{
    background-color:#2e9fff;
    color:#fff;
    border-color: #1e6fCf;
}
```

Comment: oh yeah! it really looks better with darker border